# Cron job script working from browser but not from scheduler?

Tags: php, html, email, cron

Here is my PHP page code which I will send emails but I am not able to give a path to the DB connection file which is perfectly working if I run the script through the browser.

Edit: I have updated code with Include and File Directory. Now I'm getting other errors - screenshot updated.

```
#!/usr/bin/php70
include __DIR__.'/db_connection.php';
include __DIR__.'/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

/* Date time sent emails */
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Karachi'));

$email_query = "SELECT *FROM marketing_email WHERE email_timer = '1' ";
$email_result = mysqli_query($db, $email_query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($email_result) > 0) {
while ($email_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($email_result)) {

    $attechment_query = "SELECT *FROM marketing_email_attechements WHERE marketing_email_id = '".$email_rows['id']."' AND status = '1' ";
    $attechment_result = mysqli_query($db, $attechment_query);
    if ($attechment_result) {
        $path = array();
        while ($attechment_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($attechment_result)) {
            $path[] = '../uploads/email-files/'.date('dmY').'-'.$attechment_rows['filename'];
        }
    }
    // exit();
    if ($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:00') >= $email_rows['email_datetime']) {
        /* Send email */
        $subject = $email_rows['subject'];
        $msg     = $email_rows['message'];
        $to      = $email_rows['receiver_email'];
            
        //Create a new PHPMailer instance
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        //Set the hostname of the mail server
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        // use
        $mail->Port = 587;
        
        for($ct=0;$ct<count($path);$ct++){
            $mail->AddAttachment($path[$ct]);
        }
        // $mail->AddAttachment($path);
        //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
        );
        //Whether to use SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
        $mail->Username = 'soomroa923@gmail.com';
        //Password to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Password = "abdullah999";
        //Set who the message is to be sent from
        $mail->From = 'from@example.com';
        $mail->FromName = 'Job-interview';
        //Set an alternative reply-to address
        //$mail->addReplyTo(‘hidaya@gmail.com', 'hidaya');

        //Set who the message is to be sent to
        $mail->addAddress($to,'Job-interview');
        //Set the subject line
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->msgHTML($msg);
        //send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
         "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        //header("location:manage_users.php?flag=3");
        } 
        else {
            $update_query = "UPDATE marketing_email SET email_timer = '0' WHERE id = '".$email_rows['id']."' ";
            $update_result = mysqli_query($db, $update_query);
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "time not exist";
    }
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //location.href="../email-list.php";
    console.log('Thank you email has been sent');
</script>
<?php
}
else{
echo "Data not found";
}
?>
```

I am trying to schedule emails for that I created a cron job which gave me an error on file which works fine from the browser.

Here is screenshot from my cpanel when i am trying to create cron job and testing it's file if it runs or not.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rename your cron command to `/usr/bin/php70 -f /path/to/your.php`, and make sure`/usr/bin/php70` is a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with a similar problem.
I think I see one thing that looks wrong. On line 19 your code says

$path[] = '../uploads/email-files/'.date('dmY').'-'.$attechment_rows['filename'];

This is a relative path which will not work from the command line, which is how cron jobs run, but works fine in a browser.
Try changing the start of that line to something like:

$path[] = dirname( **DIR** ) . '/uploads/email-files/'.date('dmY')...

(DIR should have two underscores before and after it) If you try a few echo statements you will get the path right.